# How to receive an event in c# which is raised in vb?

Tags: c#

I need to use a legacy library written in visual basic which raises some events. Actually I do not know how to bind an action in my new c# project if one of the events are raised.

The event in the legacy code is defined like this

```
Public Event OnStartOfMainLoop(ByRef evt As HandlerEvent, ByVal datapath As String, ByRef skipRun As Boolean, ByRef refreshQueueMap As Boolean, ByRef refreshFormsMap As Boolean)
```

and raised

```
RaiseEvent OnStartOfMainLoop(evt, datapath, skipRun, refreshQueueMap, refreshFormsMap)
```

Now how can I receive this event in my new project and handle it?

Comment: `objectWithThisEvent.OnStartOfMainLoop += MyHandler`

Comment: Why do you have `ByRef` booleans being passed into your event handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within C#, you simply need to subscribe to the event:

```
obj.OnStartOfMainLoop += MyEventHandlerMethod;

public void MyEventHandlerMethod(ref HandlerEvent evt, string datapath,
        ref bool skipRun, ref bool refreshQueueMap, ref bool refreshFormsMap)
{
    //Handle the event here
}
```

Where `obj` is the instance of the object you are subscribing to, and `MyEventHandlerMethod` is the method you want to route it to.

You will need to ensure that the handler method correctly implements the required signature of your event.

Comment: I think you'll have to add `ref` modifiers, because the OP's parameters are `ByRef`. Could be wrong though, haven't used VB.NET in a while.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin Yeah, I've updated the answer. thanks.